# How do I play this correctly in key or without?

Tags: keyboard, transposition

im trying to learn [this song](http://www.zhaogepu.com/jianpu/168249.html) by a Chinese singer.

If you look at the score here (it's a keyboard score) you will see on top left corner it says key in Bb however when I transpose that to my keyboard the left hand, it doesn't sound right. Does it mean in this score I'm suppose to transpose my right hand and not my left?

If yes I don't think my Roland entry level model is capable of splitting it

Comment: It's only a guess - never seen this stuff before- but the chords are written in Bb, and the numbers relate to notes from that key - 1=Bb, 2=C, 3=D etc. If it was played in a different key, the numbers would still relate to the new key, but the chords won't fit. More often than not (!) both hands play in the same key in one song.

Comment: I doubt you need to have hands in different keys. Is there any chance you could post a link to the song on youtube, or at least give us the title of the song (like me, quite a few of our users won't be able to read Chinese).

Comment: Er, where is the score?

Comment: Why not just play it in Bb. It's only two flats. What you're asking doesn't make any sense. You're asking to transpose left hand only or right hand. Just learn both hands in the same key. If you have an entry level piano I doubt you can split transpose

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the links are dead, and the question no longer contains enough information to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to transpose anything.  If I were trying to play this on a keyboard from the sheet music you linked to, I would just play the chords in the key of B flat as written (B flat, Dm, E flat, Bflat etc.) and play the melody with the right hand.  The numbers refer to the notes of the scale so in B flat, 1 = B flat, 2 = C, 3 = D, 4 = E flat, 5 = F, 6 = G and 7 = A.  Hope that helps!